# Requests.get = incomplete response from server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm working on a smart thermostat API called Netatmo and I would like to have notifications on when to open windows to refresh the house and when to close them to avoid big temperatures. But this is my problem :

When I send a requests.get to the API I get that tiny response body:

```
b'{"status":"ok","time_server":1597066870}'
```

But when I try the same function on the API documentation I get something like this:

```
    {
"status": "ok",
"time_server": 1597065676,
"body": {
"home": {
"id": "5dc3d9761073ae00191e164b",
"modules": [
{
"id": "70:ee:50:3e:02:e4",
"type": "NAPlug",
"firmware_revision": 210,
"plug_connected_boiler": 0,
"rf_strength": 111,
"wifi_strength": 50
},
{
"id": "04:00:00:3d:ff:04",
"anticipating": false,
"battery_level": 4335,
"firmware_revision": 72,
"rf_strength": 67,
"boiler_status": false,
"type": "NATherm1",
"boiler_valve_comfort_boost": false,
"reachable": true,
"bridge": "70:ee:50:3e:02:e4",
"battery_state": "full"
},
{
"id": "09:00:00:04:94:ed",
"battery_level": 2868,
"firmware_revision": 81,
"rf_strength": 79,
"type": "NRV",
"reachable": true,
"bridge": "70:ee:50:3e:02:e4",
"battery_state": "high"
}
],
"rooms": [
{
"id": "2644958090",
"anticipating": false,
"open_window": false,
"reachable": true,
"therm_measured_temperature": 26.2,
"therm_setpoint_temperature": 7,
"therm_setpoint_mode": "hg",
"therm_setpoint_start_time": 1596003196,
"therm_setpoint_end_time": 0
},
{
"id": "2984987671",
"anticipating": false,
"heating_power_request": 0,
"open_window": false,
"reachable": true,
"therm_measured_temperature": 27.5,
"therm_setpoint_temperature": 7,
"therm_setpoint_mode": "hg",
"therm_setpoint_start_time": 1596003196,
"therm_setpoint_end_time": 0
}
]
}
}
}
```

This is the function I use on my script, maybe there is something wrong ?

```
def temperature_int():
netatmo_headers = {'accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Bearer {}'.format(token)}
temp_int = requests.get(netatmo_temp_url, headers=netatmo_headers)
return temp_int
```

Could you help me with that ? Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What *exactly* is the code you are running, what are you getting in response, and what do you expect to get instead?

Comment: Server notify you that request have been received but return nothing. It means that either headers or query params are not recognized by server.

Comment: I try to get the "therm_measured_temperature" variable in the 'body' dict. But all I have is a line with the OK status and the time of the server. On the webpage of the API (https://dev.netatmo.com/apidocumentation/energy#homestatus) I have the whole response.